# Which API to use for 'Login with Instagram' button

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram

I'm trying to add a 'Login with Instagram' button to my app. I'm having trouble working out which API to use, should I use the [old process](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) or the new Graph API?

The Graph API docs don't reference Instagram login, only Facebook.

Comment: why would you want to use something that is deprecated and will definitely stop working sooner or later? of course you should use the new api. just use the regular facebook login with instagram permissions. it´s all in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use httpwebrequest 
And using POST to this https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/accounts/login/